# using foreach to access a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, collections, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to access the values of objects(of type Meal) stored in a list. Then I am calling a database query to save these values into the          database .

This is the code I'm using :

```
foreach (Meal ml in mVals)
            {
                    mID = ml.mealID;
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(mID));
                    string oString2 = " INSERT into [dbo].[OrderMeal] (orderId,mealId,quantity) " + " VALUES ('" + orderId + "','" + mID + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(quant.Text) + "') ;";
                    SqlCommand oCmd2 = new SqlCommand(oString2, myConnection);
                    oCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

However, this only works for the last value in the list. The next loop iteration seems to be doing the same function, thereby saving the same record, giving an

> error of violating the primary key constraint .

Is there some error in the way I am looping through the List?

Comment: Can you add information about the structure of the `OrderMeal` table?

Comment: Where is OrderID ? Are You passing nothing to orderID ?

Comment: Your code makes me conclude that you are passing the same `orderId` throughout the enitre loop.

Comment: Before anything else, you should learn about parameterized SQL. Stop embedding values directly into SQL - it's horribly insecure (and brittle in the face of *normal* values containing apostrophes, for example.)

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) would like to have a talk with you. And you should be using [using blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @JonSkeet That's very true, but for some reason or the other, the client read about SQL injection somewhere, and wants it possible. ???

Comment: @HarveySpecter Yes, I am passing the same orderId. However the primary key is a combination of the orderid and the meal id

Comment: @CDamsinghe: They *want* to be able to compromise their own database? Are you sure they didn't misunderstand? I would be very nervous about writing any code for a client insisting on deliberately including SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm pretty sure they understood, but its kind of a mandatory thing for me personally, so I can't really do anything about it

Comment: You may be accessing same list again that's why you are getting this error. Can u make sure you loop through new list every time ?

Comment: @CDamsinghe: You're showing the mealID, can you confirm that the mealID is different on item in the list AND that combination of OrderID and mealID doesn't already exist in the DB?

Comment: Where 'orderId' is defined, i think its not updated thorughout the loop, so everytime in primary key it will try ti insert same value, so that is error, can you update this ?

Comment: Like you say, primary key is a combination of orderId and mealId, that leads to duplication here because the mealId wont be unique for each item in the loop. You might have a look in there for that.

Answer (score 0):

What the structure of OrderMeal table?
Probably you have primary key in your table, and you need to vetify that you don't duplicate him.

try to enter the value in the list from the sql management.
verify that you don't have special characters in each item in the list( like comma and Apostrophe).

I think you can concatenate a set of insert statement and then ExcuteNonQuery for better performance.